# Exe download not working in IE 10

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis

In IIS, a virtual directory is created an few html pages are placed. In one of the html pages, there is a link which points to an .exe file.

When tried to click on the .exe link in the html file, the .exe downloads successfully in chrome and firefox but not in IE 10.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the link you are using. And what operating system it does not work on too please. And does right click "save as" work ?

Comment: OS: Win7 (64-bit)

"Save as" works but saves the file as _exe name rather than .exe

Comment: This sounds like IE's SmartScreen filter which blocks (or dissuades, at least) certain downloads, especially EXE files. Look for a red or yellow information bar at the bottom of the browser window when you try to download your file, it will contain further instructions.

Comment: I turned off the SmartScreen filter, still no success in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved by applying following solution.

1. Created a new folder in the website virtual directory and then placed the .exe in it.
2. In IIS, go to the new folder in the hierarchy, IIS properties > HTTP Response Headers > Add header with following key-value pair. Key: Content-disposition, Value: Attachment.
3. Restart IIS.

After performing above steps, .exe download in IE 10 worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming issue and maybe shouldn't be here.

In my experience it is always a variant of somthing corruptet in windows land.

Sometimes its user accounts, and most often a bad IE upgrade.

When it doesen't work. **Reinstall IE**.

There is a whole KB on Microsoft how to fix this. But cant seem to find it right now.

*Edit*

Well here it is [Nothing happens when you click a link in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175775/en-us)